# Does SE have a social life/relationships questions site

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was wondering if there are any sites where I can ask questions about social life and public relationships - like how to confront insults and deal with them, how to build someone up,  etc.?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's the fairly new [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) site that comes to mind.

The [tour](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour) there says:

> Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people looking to improve their interpersonal communication skills.

I don't think there is anything else that comes close.